unknown urls in my Google Analytics performance dashboard
I have a hobby wordpress website with around 4 pages and 4 posts in total. Google notified me that my website has "malware". The link that I was notified was this:

I checked my Google analytics performance and I am seeing the below links that are top-hit pages:

None of those are mine, except the root appears to be my website.
I logged into admin-console of wordpress, I cannot see these pages/posts. I logged into CPanel filemanager of my hosting and checked through all PHP and could not find any code that I could point out was malicious. I installed WordFence, GOTMLS.net antimalware scanner, both of them came back with nothing.
I am totally lost as to what to do next. Any pointers or advice will be very helpful.

fyi this is the wrong site for this, as it's not a programming question (nor is it a [tag:php] question.

Well, it could be just spam. There's nothing you can do to it in GA4. Google decided to remove the filters/views feature. Just ignore that traffic. Make reports that filter it out by the hostname or some other dimension.
If you use GTM to deploy your analytics (the best practice), you can add some checks there to make sure it wouldn't work if used on a different site. But it would still not save you from spam.

Thanks @BNazaruk. I feel compelled to do something as Google has determined that "your website has some pages with malicious content". Wouldn't that mean they might permanently mark my website as 'malware'?

Errr... I've never seen this message in GA. Is it coming from GA or GSC? Usually when Google talks about malware, it's not wrong. If you haven't updated the WP engine for a while, it's bound to be hacked. You'll have to remove compromised pages.
